# For in dentro de For in

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for

No estaría pudiendo hacer que el siguiente código logre añadirle un **ID** a cada objeto dentro del primer **arreglo**

```
const people=[
  {first_name:"john",last_name:"doe"},
  {first_name:"mary",last_name:"beth"}
];

const id = ['abc' ,'xyz'] 


for(const x in id){
        for(const y in people){
                people[y].id = id[x]
        }
}


console.log(people)
```

Esto retorna:

```
[
  { first_name: 'john', last_name: 'doe', id: 'xyz' },
  { first_name: 'mary', last_name: 'beth', id: 'xyz'} 
]
```

Cuál sería la manera más adecuada para poder asignarle un nuevo **key/value** a cada objeto respetando los valores del segundo **array**?

Comment: No te aconsejo usar un `for ... in ...` con un array, es la forma más **lenta** de recorrerlo.

Comment: mejor usar .map()

Comment: Gracias por lo señalado. Es verdad, he leído algo al respecto en otros medios y coinciden que map es una manera mucho más dinámica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no necesitas crear un nuevo array, yo usaría un for clásico:

```js
const people=[
  {first_name:"john",last_name:"doe"},
  {first_name:"mary",last_name:"beth"}
];

const id = ['abc' ,'xyz'] 

function addId(arrayWithObjects, arrayOfIds) {
   if (arrayWithObjects.length !== arrayOfIds.length) {
     return;
   }
   for (let i = 0; i < arrayWithObjects.length; i++) {
     arrayWithObjects[i].id = arrayOfIds[i];
   }
   
}
addId(people,id)

console.log(people);
```

En otro caso, podrías usar un map, como recomienda @AngelCordones en su respuesta, pero yo crearía un nuevo objeto para realmente dejar el array original igual:

```js
const people=[
 {first_name:"john",last_name:"doe"},
 {first_name:"mary",last_name:"beth"}
];
const id = ['abc' ,'xyz'] 

var nuevoArray = people.map(({first_name, last_name}, index) => {
   
  return {
    first_name,
    last_name,
    id: id[index]
  };
});

console.log(nuevoArray);
console.log(people);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Pablo por tu respuesta. Me ha gustado la opción de map sin la necesidad de crear un arreglo pero si generando un nuevo objeto. Esta alternativa me resultó muy eficiente. No descarto las demás opciones como igual de válidas!

Answer (score 3):

te propondria usar array.map y usar el index del propio array para coger los valores del segundo, de esta manera:

```
const people=[
 {first_name:"john",last_name:"doe"},
 {first_name:"mary",last_name:"beth"}
];
const id = ['abc' ,'xyz'] 

var nuevoArray = people.map((person, index)=>{
   person['id'] = id[index];
   return person;
});
```

Comment: Para mi es una una respuesta correcta, pero estás creando un array nuevo a la vez que modificando los objetos del array antiguo. Es un detalle que podría ser importante no pasar por alto

Comment: es cierto que creo un nuevo array, yo lo preferiria asi, pero se podria sobreescribir el actual directamente con el mismo codigo simplemente. en vez de `var nuevoArray`, podria ser `people = people.map(....)`

Comment: Lo que me preocupa es que se quiera tener un nuevo array y el antiguo y el OP no se de cuenta del detalle. Como digo, me parece una respuesta correcta porque parece que el OP no quiere un nuevo array y podría simplemente hacer como dices, sobreescribiendo.

Comment: gracias por la aclaracion de todos modos, no sabia que de esa manera se modificaba tambien el original, en mi caso suelo desechar ese original porque los datos no me suelen ser utilies y por eso tengo que mapearlos.

Comment: tremendo. Muchas gracias @AngelCordones!

Answer (score 2):

El primer bucle `for` se itera un total de dos veces. En la primera iteración, asigna el valor `1` al `id` de cada persona, en la segunda iteración, asigna el valor `2`, de forma que estas sobrescribiendo el mismo valor.

Una forma de hacerlo sería declarando un contador que se vaya incrementando a la hora de asignar el valor de `id`:

```
const people=[
    {first_name:"john",last_name:"doe"},
    {first_name:"mary",last_name:"beth"}
];

let cont = 1;

for(const x in people){
    people[x].id = cont;
    cont++;
}
```

---

Si quieres que el `id` provenga de un array, puedes usar ese mismo contador para asignarle el valor del array. Esto asigna lo valores de forma consecutiva.

```
const people=[
    {first_name:"john",last_name:"doe"},
    {first_name:"mary",last_name:"beth"}
];

const id = ['abc' ,'xyz'] 
let cont = 0;

for(const x in people){
    people[x].id = id[cont];
    cont++;
}
```

Comment: Gracias Fran por tu pronta respuesta; es válido lo de asignar un auto incrementador pero ¿qué pasaría si cada ID que otorga el array es un hash aleatorio? Objetivamente viene por ese lado la cuestión

Comment: El contador que sea el índice de tu array de IDs

Comment: Claro, pero la cuestión es tengo un array con distintos IDs (imaginemos que tenemos en este momento dos completamente distintos y alfanumericos) y al array de objetos de usuarios le quiero asignar a cada uno un ID

Comment: Has editado la pregunta original por lo que la respuesta que te he dado no vale en este caso..

Comment: Te he editado la respuesta, creo que es lo que estas buscando.

Comment: Gracias @Fran por el aporte. Excelente lo del contador. Lo voy a tener en cuenta para otras ocasiones. Un cordial saludo

Answer (score 1):

El for de `people` dentro de `id` recorre todos los registros de `people` por cada elemento de `id`, por ello siempre va a quedar el último, asigna todos los valores y queda el último porque no es sobreescrito por nada. En realidad, por cada `id` corresponde un `people` aparentemente en el mismo orden, entonces lo correcto sería hacer una sola iteración. Te han puesto varios ejemplos, te dejo uno usando spread operator para unir los objetos, que lo hace bastante corto:

```js
const people=[
  {first_name:"john",last_name:"doe"},
  {first_name:"mary",last_name:"beth"}
];

const id = ['abc' ,'xyz'] 

const res = people.map((e, i) => ({ ...e, id: id[i] }));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Tremendo Emmeus la alternativa de map + spread operator. Simple, en una sola línea. Muchas gracias por el aporte!!